# Confusion about Migration to Incremental Repairs in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, bigdata, nosql

I am a bit confused about migration to **incremental repairs** in *Cassandra*, and how it impacts *Leveled Compaction Strategy (LCS)*.

From [this](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/more-efficient-repairs) blog, it seems *LCS* uses *STCS* for unrepaired *SSTables*. But, there is a comment to clarify that- its no longer the case since [2.1.2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8004). However, all the *DataStax* docs mention that- we need to follow a migration procedure if using incremental repair and *LCS*, as mentioned [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/opsRepairNodesMigration.html). This seems to indicate that, while using LCS, we need to first do full sequential repairs, along with the use of `sstablerepairedset` utility to indicate what is repaired, before using incremental repairs.

My understanding from this link is that, these migration steps are needed only when using *LCS*, and that is to avoid *LCS* doing *STCS* on all *SSTables*, unless they are repaired. If we are using *STCS*, then these steps are not required.

The thing that is not clear to me is- if *LCS* is no longer using *STCS* for un-repaired tables, then what is the point of these migration steps.

Does that means that, no migration is needed, and we can just start using *-inc* option in repair commands without having to do steps mentioned [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/opsRepairNodesMigration.html)? Or, is there anything else I am missing, because of which we still need these migration steps?

I also checked that these steps are mentioned even for *C* 3.0*, and no where it says that- if you are on 2.1.2 or greater then these steps are not required. Can someone please clarify if I am missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Migration procedure is no longer required for LCS after [CASSANDRA-8004](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8004), so you're fine just running nodetool repair -inc option in the first time.